# Android xml properties does not always populate

Tags: android, xml

I am having an issue where the properties window in the xml editor does not always load the properties. Sometimes the loading is delayed, sometimes it never loads. I can not track down the rhyme or reason for this.

Further more when this happens all of the options such as the green droid, the theme selector, the preview config selector are gone as well.

SDK Tools 22.6.1

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

- Restarting Eclipse does not fix it.
- Clean/Build does not fix it
- Deleting all xml from the file, and pasting it back in, then closing the file and reopening it seems to fix it sometimes.
- Randomly doing all 3 of the above in no particular order over no particular number of iterations seems to eventually work

Has anyone had this issue, and have you found a solution?

Comment: I've seen this with tools 22.6.2 as well. I know of no solution other than to close the file then reopen it.

Comment: The last build tools upgrade (22.6.2) also have eclipse upgrades.  Did you also update Eclipse?

Comment: I will do this tonight, at home when I have access to my 1gbps connection. Maybe all the updates will fix this, maybe not.